# How to "walk" this tree consisting of lists, tuples and strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tree

The tree structure:

```
T
|__A1
|   |__B1
|   |__B2
|       |__D1
|__A2
    |__C1
    |__C2
    |__C3
        |__E1
            |__F1
           E2
            |__G1
            |__G2
```

is parsed to:

```
[('T',
  [('A1', ['B1', ('B2', ['D1'])]),
   ('A2', ['C1', 'C2', ('C3', [('E1', ['F1']), ('E2', ['G1', 'G2'])])])])]
```

or (the same thing):

```
[('T',
  [('A1',
    [
     'B1',
     ('B2', ['D1'])
    ]
   ),
   ('A2',
    [
     'C1',
     'C2',
     ('C3',
      [
       ('E1', ['F1']),
       ('E2', ['G1', 'G2'])
      ]
     )
    ]
   )
  ]
)]
```

How could one iterate/traverse/walk a tree formatted in this way? I know this is rather a specific problem, but I'm really stuck at this point. The expected goal is to output *all the possible routes from root to each end-node*, like this (type is not important, but could be for example: lists of strings):

```
T A1 B1
T A1 B2 D1
T A2 C1
T A2 C2
T A2 C3 E1 F1
T A2 C3 E2 G1
T A2 C3 E2 G2
```

The code is nowhere close to working but it may show the general inclination:

```
formatted_tree = [('T',[('A1', ['B1', ('B2', ['D1'])]),('A2', ['C1', 'C2', ('C3', [('E1', ['F1']), ('E2', ['G1', 'G2'])])])])]

def walk(n):
    if isinstance(n, basestring):
        yield n # end-branches
    else:
        if isinstance(n, tuple): # root,[bra,nch,es]
            yield n[0]
            walk(n[1])
        elif isinstance(n, list): # LIST=branches (can be tuples or string)
            for branch in n:
                walk(branch)

[path for path in walk(formatted_tree)]
```

Comment: So where's your code, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: OK. The code is not working. I'll paste it but it's nowhere close. As for what I'm trying to achieve here is to traverse the formatted tree (list variable).

Comment: Don't just dump it in, cut it down to a [mcve]. If it's *"nowhere close"*, you probably aren't ready for an SO question yet either.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, I'll try to get the function working, otherwise I'll rollback this question as it may be confusing/useless/obscure etc.

Comment: You're on the right track. For starters, you can't just call `walk(x)` by itself because that creates a generator and throws it away. You need to iterate over it and yield what's within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shall work

```
tree = [('T',
  [('A1', ['B1', ('B2', ['D1'])]),
   ('A2', ['C1', 'C2', ('C3', [('E1', ['F1']), ('E2', ['G1', 'G2'])])])])]


def print_node(header, tree):
    if isinstance(tree,str):
        return [header+' '+str(tree)]
    else:
        head, tail = tree
        return reduce(lambda a,b:a+b,[print_node(header + ' ' + head,t_element) for t_element in tail])

def print_tree(tree):
    children = tree[0]
    print '\n'.join(print_node('',children))

print_tree(tree)
```

It keeps the list of result in memory and performs a simple recursion. print_tree is only a wrapper to put the input in the right form.
Hope it helps !